# how can I change the table size to be suitable for the data grid view size?

Tags: c#

[image]

this is a C# windows form application and am fetching data from database as a data reader object to show it in the data grid view  shown in the picture but I can't set the size of the 
table to be suitable with the data grid view .

here's the code :

```
private void ViewTable()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Abdullah-PC;Initial Catalog=SmartPharmacyDB;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "select drugname , companyname, price, instock, expirationdate from drugtab order by drugname";
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Drug Name", "drugname");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Company Name", "companyname");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Price", "price");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("In Stock", "instock");
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Expires On", "expirationdate");

        int i = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr["drugname"];
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dr["companyname"];
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dr["price"];
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dr["instock"];
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = dr["expirationdate"];
            i++;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want the column widths to autosize? There's a property on the DataGridView called AutoSizeColumnsMode. This can be set via the properties Visual Studio panel. Set this to 'Fill'.